# Combining Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

In the following code I needed to read in a list of five student names and marks for five quizzes for each student, which loads the names in an ArrayList of type String and the quiz marks in an ArrayList of type Integer. I have broken this problem down by the two different ArrayLists, and I am looking to combine them but not sure.

The following code reads five students names and loads the names in an ArrayList of type String

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class QuizAveragee
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        final int NAMELIMIT = 5 ;
        final int QUIZLIMIT = 5 ;
        ArrayList<String> sNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> sFamily = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Load the five names of the students in the arraylist
        for(int i = 1; i<=NAMELIMIT; i++)
        {
            String[] input = in.nextLine().split("\\s+");

            sNames.add(input[0]);
            sFamily.add(input[1]);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<NAMELIMIT; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Name: " + sNames.get(i) + " " + sFamily.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

With the following input:

```
Sally Mae 90 80 45 60 75
Charlotte Tea 60 75 80 90 70
Oliver Cats 55 65 76 90 80
Milo Peet 90 95 85 75 80
Gavin Brown 45 65 75 55 80
```

It generates:

```
Name: Sally Mae
Name: Charlotte Tea
Name: Oliver Cats
Name: Milo Peet
Name: Gavin Brown
```

I then needed to make a part of the program that will read in five quizzes for each student and load the quiz marks in an ArrayList of type integer. This is what I have generated for this part.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class heya
{
    public static final int QUIZLIMIT = 5;
    public static Scanner readQuiz;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        readQuiz = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (readQuiz.hasNextLine()) {
            ArrayList<Integer> quizMarks = readArrayList(readQuiz.nextLine());
            computerAverage(quizMarks);
        }
    }

    // Load quiz marks
    public static ArrayList<Integer> readArrayList(String input)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> quiz = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner readQuiz = new Scanner(input);
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= QUIZLIMIT)
        {
            if (readQuiz.hasNextInt()) {
                quiz.add(readQuiz.nextInt());
                i++;
            }
            else {
                readQuiz.next(); // Toss the next read token
            }
        }
        return quiz;
    }

    // Compute the average of quiz marks
    public static void computerAverage(ArrayList<Integer>quiz)
    {
        int total = 0 ;
        for(Integer value : quiz)
        {
            total = total + value;
        }
        System.out.println("Quiz Avg: "+ (total/QUIZLIMIT));
    }
}
```

which gives the output:

```
Quiz Avg: 70
Quiz Avg: 75
Quiz Avg: 73
Quiz Avg: 85
Quiz Avg: 64
```

However, I need to combine these programs which I am not quite sure how to do. The given input:

```
Sally Mae 90 80 45 60 75
Charlotte Tea 60 75 80 90 70
Oliver Cats 55 65 76 90 80
Milo Peet 90 95 85 75 80
Gavin Brown 45 65 75 55 80
```

should give:

```
Name: Sally Mae Quiz Avg: 70
Name: Charlotte Tea Quiz Avg: 75
Name: Oliver Cats Quiz Avg: 73
Name: Milo Peet Quiz Avg: 85
Name: Gavin Brown Quiz Avg: 64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished much more simply with a single loop, assuming you know the data will be in the right form (a first and last name followed by 5 grades) and you don't need to store the names or grades for later use.

```
public class QuizAveragee {
  private static final int NAMELIMIT = 5;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //these lines are not needed but OP asked for the values to be stored in arrays
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> averages = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < NAMELIMIT; i++) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[] words = line.split(" ");
        String name = words[0] + " " + words[1];
        double average = findAverage(words[2], words[3], words[4], words[5], words[6]);
        System.out.println("Name : " + name + " Quiz Avg: " + average);

        //these lines are not needed but OP asked for the values to be stored in arrays
        names.add(name);
        averages.add(average);
    }
  }

  private static double findAverage(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
    double sum = Double.parseDouble(a) + Double.parseDouble(b) + Double.parseDouble(c) + Double.parseDouble(d) + Double.parseDouble(e);
    return (sum / NAMELIMIT);
  }
}
```

If you do need to store these values for later, I suggest making use of the fact that Java is an Object oriented language and declaring a `Student` object which can hold the names and grades of your students. You could do that like this:

```
public class Student {
  private ArrayList<Integer> grades;
  private String fName;
  private String lName;

  public Student(String inputLine) {
    grades = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] lineSplit = inputLine.split(" ");
    fName = lineSplit[0];
    lName = lineSplit[1];
    for (int i = 2; i < lineSplit.length; i++) {
      grades.add(Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[i]));
    }
  }

  private double computeAvg() {
    double sum = 0;
    for (Integer grade : grades) {
      sum = sum + grade;
    }
    return sum / grades.count();
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + fName + " " + lName + " Quiz Avg: " + computeAvg();
  }
}

private static final int NAMELIMIT = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < NAMELIMIT; i++) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        Student s = new Student(line);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i add that to my code? we havent used private either yet unfortunately

Comment: `int average` should be `double average` You are also missing the closing brace for main.

Comment: Simply replace your old main method with the one i rewrote. You can declare a private method the same way you declare public methods in your existing code - just add them below the main method.

Comment: should i add replace that main method with the first program I made?

Comment: @janedone This answer appears self-contained and runnable as a `Student.java` file

Comment: @janedone Edited my code slightly. You can just replace your entire ComputeAveragee class with the first block of code I provided. You will still need whatever import statements you were using before.

Comment: @janedone If this helps you it would be awesome if you upvoted it and accepted it as an answer.

Comment: its a little confusing not sure how to combine everything

Comment: @janedone The code I provided should combine everything - simply replace your `ComputeAveragee` class with the first block of code I wrote and run it.

Comment: yes that works perfectly actually the only thing is i needed to use arrays

Comment: @janedone No problem - we can modify the code to store the values in arrays. See my edit. Keep in mind there is no real reason to have them in an array if we aren't using the array for anything, though.

Comment: this was a section on arraylists so it was practice for this topic

Comment: @janedone Yes, it now stores the names and averages in arrays

Comment: perfect thanks a lot, one last question, if i wanted to take those privates out and not use them how could i go about that?

Comment: @janedone you could just change the word `private` to `public`. In this case there is no difference. Would that work?

Comment: so just to confirm now that I am going through the code, this code does use the String ArrayList and Int ArrayList?

Comment: also why is the line public static final int NAMELIMIT = 5;   before the line    public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: @janedone You can declare a variable outside the main method if you make that variable static. You could also move it back inside the method if you want - it is just better style to have constants at the top of the file, outside methods.

Comment: okay awesome   just working on now trying to get the quiz averages weighted out of 15 instead of out of 100 so it would be 10.5 11.25 10.95 12.75 9.6

Comment: @janedone I think you should be able to figure out how to do that from the simple code we have now. Try on your own and if you have more issues, respond here or open a new question. Good luck!

Comment: yes i should be able to, now im just left with the easy part, thanks for your help

Comment: i just noticed one thing, i needed to read the quiz marks in a Integer ArrayList not a double ArrayList

Comment: @janedone I don't see how that is possible. Right now we have an array list of doubles containing the averages for each student. That is because the average might not be an int. For example if the grades are 100 and 99, the average will be 99.5. We store it as a double because we would simply store the wrong value if we stored it as an int.

Comment: @janedone If you want to store each value of each grade for each student, I suggest you look at the second part of my answer, where I show how to create a `Student` object. This will be more complicated, though.

Comment: yes this example asks for a ArrayList with a String which we have done, and a ArrayList with Int, this Int ArrayList will read in 5 of the each quiz marks for every student

Comment: havent looked into objects yet